# How to use Nordic UART Service with Movesense?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, gatt, movesense

I want to make use of BLE UART (BleNordicUART module) with my custom firmware for printing and streaming sensor data. I didn't find much information regarding BLE UART in the wiki or sources.

I have tried modifying ble_std_services sample app by adding call to send_ble_nus_data function in CustomBleController.cpp file:

```
    send_ble_hr_measurement(hr, &(hrdata.rrData[0]), hrdata.rrData.size());
    send_ble_nus_data(&uart_data,sizeof(uart_data));
```

However, the nRFUART / nrfConnect mobiles app don't find BLE Uart service. I have turned on/off Bluetooth and verified with other devices as well, so it doesn't seem to be a GATT caching issue.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled NUS in App.cpp

```
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleStandardHRS, false)
OPTIONAL_CORE_MODULE(BleNordicUART, true)
```

Notice that with 1.8.1 you can not have both HRS and NUS enabled